# Unable to get the socket id on the front end

Tags: reactjs, express, user-interface, websocket, socket.io

I need to get each socket's id on the frontend so later I can distinguish each connection. When I print socketRef.current I can clearly see whatever is inside it and even "id" in it but only the "id" is the thing I cannot print from there (if I print "io" or "ids" it works). Why I cannot print the "id" field? Is there a way to get id properly from the backend?

```js
const socketRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
    socketRef.current = io.connect('http://localhost:5000')
    console.log(socketRef.current.id)

}, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

connect io and on socket `connect` get `socket.id`

```
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
socket.on("connect", () => {
  console.log(socket.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe need to wait for the `connect` first:

```
useEffect(() => {
  socketRef.current = io.connect('http://localhost:5000')
  socketRef.current.on('connect', ()=> {
  console.log(socketRef.current.socket.sessionid);
});
    }, []);
```